# Python converting string to list

Tags: python

I am sending data between python socket connection. The data is an array and I am sending it in blocks of each line. When the data comes in it looks like this:

```
data = '[1,0,1]'
```

I want to convert this back into array form so I can then add it back into my master array that is being sent over. Any idea how I can convert this string back into an array.

Comment: If all your data is numeric it might be better to send numbers rather than stringifying your list

Comment: You could use eval(data) which will convert your string to a list

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=literal_eval#ast.literal_eval).

Comment: `data = '[1,0,1]'` is not an array, it is a list. You should be sending data in some sort of serialized format, not just calling `str` on your object and pretending it is serialization.

Answer (score 3):

```
import json

data = '[1,0,1]'

data = json.loads(data)
```

Out:

```
[1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: This will not work if the list includes strings instead of integers